# javascript - query object graph?

Tags: javascript, object

Given an object like this:

```
var obj = {
        first:{
            second:{
                third:'hi there'
            }
        }
    };
```

And a key like this "first.second.third"

How can I get the value of the nested object "hi there"?

I think maybe the Array.reduce function could help, but not sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got it:

```
args.reduce(function(prev, current) {return prev[current];}, obj);
```

Answer (score 5):

Yes, with [`Array.prototype.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Objects/Array/Reduce) you can get a sweet and short function:

```
function getNestedValue(obj, key) {
  return key.split('.').reduce(function (a, b) { return a[b]; }, obj);
}

getNestedValue(obj, "first.second.third"); // "hi there"
```

Some notes:

- `Array.prototype.reduce` is part of the ECMAScript 5th Edition, is available on all browsers except IE, you can include an implementation from [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Objects/Array/Reduce).
- Object property names might contain dots, if you build an object using the bracket notation e.g. `obj['my.key'] = 'value';`